# Entity Framework Eager loading 2nd level - not populating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

The following are extracts from my code

```
namespace QuizGame.Models
{

public class QuestionBank
{

    public QuestionBank()
    {
        Status = DeleteStatus.Active;
        Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }


}

public class Question 
{
    public Question()
    {
        Status = DeleteStatus.Active;
        QuestionType = Models.QuestionType.MultipleChoice_SingleAnswer_Text;
        PossibleAnswers = new List<Answer>();
    }



    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<Answer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
 }

}
```

So Trying to get a list of Questions with Answers for a given Question Bank

The following does not seem to populate the Possible Answers

```
        var x = from g in _dc.QuestionBank
                    .Include (q => q.Questions)
                    .Include(q => q.Questions.Select(a => a.PossibleAnswers))
                where g.Status == DeleteStatus.Active &&
                g.Id == bankId
                select g.Questions;
```

I have achieve a really hacky solution

```
        var xl = new List<Question>();

        var ql = (from g in _dc.QuestionBank.Include(q => q.Questions)
                  where g.Status == DeleteStatus.Active &&
                  g.Id == bankId
                  select g.Questions).FirstOrDefault();


        foreach (Question item in ql.ToList())
        {
            var q1 = from q in _dc.Questions.Include(a => a.PossibleAnswers)
                     where q.Id == item.Id
                     select q;

            xl.Add(q1.FirstOrDefault());
        }
```

But I'm sure there is something small that I'm missing on the eager loading query which should fix the problem and make things clearer.

Comment: Delete the first `Include` ( `.Include (q => q.Questions)` ), with the second  you will include both levels. Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx)  for more info

Comment: The following looks like it should work   

       var x99 = from g in _dc.QuestionBank          
                  .Include(q => q.Questions.Select(a => a.PossibleAnswers))
                      where g.Status == DeleteStatus.Active &&
                      g.Id == bankId
                    select g.Questions;

But it only returns questions with no possible answers - I double checked the database and there are definitely PossibleAnswers associated with the question.